# Grey dirt sliding in behind navigation & tab bars

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

When I push my UITableViewController subclass it nicely slides in from the right, immediately followed by some kind of grey dirt that shows up on/under the navigation & tab bar.  It's very fast but I've been able to capture it red handedly.

(I also saw it elsewhere in my app with another view controller that slides up, here the dirt comes from below and makes the navigation bar darker.)

Any idea what this is, and more importantly how to get rid of it.

[image]

Comment: What was the view controller in the navigation stack before this one?

Comment: @kentoh Another UITableViewController subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

in my `AppDelegate` code and the effect is still there (compared to what I see in iOS' Settings app for example), but it's very faint, and the final result after animation looks normal.